# cupertino option tiles ,ios settings page style

Tags: flutter

I'm wondering which or how can design settings page like that

[image]

1-every option has a own value in right if it's has
2-hit under tile option
3- the divider not full width

is it by ListTile !! or there is another widget ?

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: create page design like that ! what's widget I should use

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple widgets uses in the above design you can not create it with `single widget`

1. Widgets You can use

   ```
   Text,Containers,ListTile,CupertinoButtons and more
   ```

   Try yourself and `Best of luck`